# Regex return match and extended matches

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Can regex return matches and extended matches. What I mean is one regex expression that can return different number of found elements depending on the structure. My text is:

```
AB : CDE / 123.456.1; 1
AC : DEF / 3.1.2
```

My return (match) should be:

```
'AB', 'CDE', '123.456.1', '1'
'AC', 'DEF','3.1.2'
```

So if there is a value after a semicolon then the regex should match and return that as well. But if is not there it should still match the part and return the rest.

My code is:

```
import re

s = '''AB : CDE / 123.456.1; 1
AC : DEF / 3.1.2'''

match1 = re.search(r'((?:AB|AC))\s*:\s*(\w+)\s*\/\s*([\w.]+)\s*(;\s*\d+)', s)
print(match1[0])

match2 = re.search(r'((?:AB|AC))\s*:\s*(\w+)\s*\/\s*([\w.]+)\s*', s)
print(match2[0])
```

Where match1 only matches the first occurrance and match2 only the second. What would be the regex to work in both cases?

Comment: Add a `?` at the end of the first pattern.

Comment: Thank you! That works! If you write an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `r'((?:AB|AC))\s*:\s*(\w+)\s*\/\s*([\w.]+)\s*(;\s*\d+)'` pattern contains an obligatory `(;\s*\d+)` pattern at the end. You need to make it *optional* and you may do it by adding a `?` quantifier after it, so as to match 1 or 0 occurrences of the subpattern.

With other minor enhancements, you may use

```
r'A[BC]\s*:\s*\w+\s*/\s*[\w.]+\s*(?:;\s*\d+)?'
```

Note all capturing groups are removed, and non-capturing ones are introduced since you only get the whole match value in the end.

**Details**

- `A[BC]` - `AB` or `AC`

  - `\s*:\s*` - a colon enclosed with 0+ whitespace chars
- `\w+` - or more word chars
- `\s*/\s*` - a `/`  enclosed with 0+ whitespace chars
- `[\w.]+` - 1 or more word or `.` chars
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:;\s*\d+)?` - an optional sequence of

  - `;` - a `;`
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits